# Pegar data param com o Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou tentando pegar informações enviadas via *POST* no Node.JS, desta forma:
Chamo a API assim:

```
$.ajax({
 method: 'POST',
 url: '/api/post',
 data: {
  xml: '<?xml version="1.0"?><query><author>John Steinbeck</author></query>'
 }
})
```

No node configurei desta forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.post('/api/post', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('ok');
})
```

Porém esse `console.log(req.body)` retorna `undefined`.

Comment: se você usar só console.log(req), ele aparece algo?

Comment: sim, mostra uma lista de propriedades e métodos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, estou presumindo que este seu código em ajax esteja rodando no mesmo URL da sua API node, por isso na url do seu ajax você não esta passando o caminho completo, somente o `/api/post`, correto?
Bom, se for isso, o que deve estar acontecendo é que faltou você adicionar o módulo body-parser ao seu projeto.
Para instalar vá na pasta raiz do seu projeto e execute o comando:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

O parâmetro --save não é obrigatório, ele serve para que fique salvo essa dependência no arquivo `package.json`.

Depois de instalado o módulo, deve importar o mesmo no seu projeto assim:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.post('/api/post', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('ok');
})
app.use(router);

/* Inicializa servidor */
app.listen(port);
```

Neste exemplo estou considerando que as informações serão enviadas utilizando o JSON, por isso a linha `app.use(bodyParser.json());`.

Para saber mais sobre esse módulo pode consultar este [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: Não funcionou, mas me ajudou. Ao invés de usar o app = express() eu usei a const router. Então ficou:
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Verdade, para dar certo ali no meu exemplo só precisaria dar um `app.use(router);` vou editar, caso outra pessoa necessite, neste exemplo que postei não precisa de outro arquivo para iniciar somente dar o comando `node app.js` (ou o nome que quiser para o arquivo .js) . Obrigado por avisar

Comment: Obrigado Murilo!